# C way to check if file exists

Tags: c, fopen

I have question about checking if file exists or not.
Which option is better?

```
source=fopen("text.txt","r");
if(source != NULL)
{
    printf("File Exists!\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

or to use

```
if (source)
{
    printf("File Exists!\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Neither of them is good because some file may not be opened even if it exists. For example, what if you don't have a permission to open it?

Comment: Also, you should close opened files.

Comment: My way, regardless of the programming language, is to assume success and handle failure when necessary. Why to check and only then open? Try to open and know how to handle failures.

Comment: @MikeCAT Okay, is there any way to check if the file is there without opening it? 
I forgot to add that line! Thanks! :)

Comment: For POSIX, you can use the `stat` function.